# Add styles for only last two spans in element

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors, highlight

Hi I have this code and each word is wrapped into span tag and I want to add styles only to the last two spans, even if `<p>` tag has `<em>` tag inside and it has `<span>` tags the condition should be the same, the last two spans in a `<p>` tag.

P.S. Without em tag it's working normally

```css
.st span:nth-last-child(-n + 2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p class="st">
  <span>With</span>
  <span>ipsum</span>
  <em>
    <span>dolor</span>
    <span>sit</span>
  </em>
  <span>amet,</span> consectetur adipisicing elit.
</p>

<p class="st">
  <span>Lorem</span>
  <span>ipsum</span>
  <em>
    <span>dolor</span>
    <span>sit</span>
  </em>
  <span>amet,</span>
  <span>consectetur</span>
  <span>adipisicing</span>
  <span>elit.</span>
</p>
```

Should work without em tag or maybe another tag can be instead

Comment: This is not possible with CSS....you need Javascript. That's not the way `nth` works in CSS

Comment: It would help if you would list **exactly** which `<span>` elements should be selected instead of describing it in prose. It's unclear if `sit` and `amet` should be selected, or only `adipisicing` and `elit` - as well as what should happen if the `<em>` includes the second-to-last `<span>`.

Comment: @Paulie_D The `:nth-last-child()`  pseudo-class only requires the syntax `An+B` where `A` and/or `B` can be negative integers, so `nth-last-child(-n3+3)` is valid, as is `(-n + 2)` as A is implicitly `-1`. There are examples of this on MDN's page.

Answer (score 1):

Check Now

target CSS This way

```
.st > span:nth-last-child(-n + 2)
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/aged-violet-5w8gyt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: it's not working like this, because spans inside em tag also needed to be highlighted, but if after em tag there are spans also need to highlights only them

Comment: in this example, spans inside em tag excluded

Comment: @ArtSamvelyan What if there's only 1 `p.st > em:last-of-type > span` while there's **also** only 1 `p.st > em:last-of-type ~ span:last-of-type` ? Does the last `span` have to be an immediate sibling of the `em` or not? What if there are other element siblings? What about non-element DOM `#text` runs? You need to think-through this scenario more.

Comment: I know all about the scenario, I said that all I need is to implement styles only to the last two spans and whether they are inside em or not

Comment: Of course, I used this .st span:nth-last-child(-n + 2) first, but in the case where there are more spans after the em tag, the spans inside the em remain hightliged, but this is not needed

Comment: for more understanding, I'm dynamically adding span tag to each word by JS, and need to keep highlighted only the last 2 spans .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your post is unclear about how `<span>` elements **inside** an immediate `p.st > em` element should be selected - my answer assumes you only want to select the last **sibling pair** of `<span>` elements **if and only if** the sibling pair is also the last children (not descendants) of their parent `p.st`.

---

- What you're asking is (currently, as of February 2022) impossible to achieve in CSS (without JavaScript) *in the general case*.

  - This is because CSS selectors can only select elements based on a very restricted set of element properties, or based on an element's ancestors, and an element's previous siblings.

    - But a selector *cannot* select elements based on *future siblings* nor descendants of other ancestors.
- In order to select "the last 2 `<span>` elements" you need a selector that can select both:

  1. The last child (not descendant) element, but only if it's a `<span>` that's also preceded by another `<span>`.
  2. The second-to-last (not descendant) element, but only if it's a `<span>` element that's also immediately followed by another `<span>`.
- Case 1 is straightforward: it's just `span + span:last-child:last-of-type {  }` or `span + span:nth-last-child(1) { }`.
- Case 2, however, is impossible: CSS only has 2 sibling selectors (`x + y` and `x ~ y`), and both of which can only be used to select the `y` sibling, **not** the `x` sibling.

  - There is the `:has()` pseudo-element function which you can use today, but only with `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll`: it cannot be used in CSS rules.

    - As of early 2022, [there is work being done to add support for a restricted form of `:has()`](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=669058) into Chromium, and it's exciting stuff, but don't hold your breath - I'm not expecting to see it go mainstream for at least another couple of years.

      - Once it is supported (and assuming it uses the `:scope` keyword) then you could use this:

        ```
        p.st:has( :scope > span + span:last-child:last-of-type ) > span + span:last-child:last-of-type,
        p.st:has( :scope > span + span:last-child:last-of-type ) > span:nth-last-child(2) { }
        ```

So this is the best we can do, right now:

- The selector below will incorrectly match the "amet" span in the first paragraph.
- I changed the colors to `red` and `yellow` so you can see which rule is selecting which element specifically.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1em;
}

div > p:first-child {
  font-size: 80%;
  color: #666;
}

p.st > span + span:nth-last-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

p.st > span:nth-last-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Does not match any span elements: even though the last element is a span, that element doesn't have an immediate span sibling:</p>
  <p class="st">
    <span>Lorem</span>
    <span>ipsum</span>
    <em>
        <span>dolor</span>
        <span>sit</span>
      </em>
    <span>amet,</span> consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>The style rules incorrectly select the &quot;sit&quot; span because they cannot select a &lt;span&gt; followed by a &lt;strong&gt;:</p>
  <p class="st">
    <span>Lorem</span>
    <span>ipsum</span>
    <strong>dolor</strong>
    <span>sit</span>
    <strong>consectetur</strong> adipisicing elit.
  </p>

</div>

<div>
  <p>In this case, the style rule does correctly select the last span sibling pair:</p>
  <p class="st">
    <span>Lorem</span>
    <span>ipsum</span>
    <em>
        <span>dolor</span>
        <span>sit</span>
      </em>
    <span>amet,</span>
    <span>consectetur</span>
    <span>adipisicing</span>
    <span>elit.</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

---

**However**, while we cannot solve this in the general-case, it is possible to abuse `:not()` and other selector functions to prevent selecting elements that match other patterns. This approach is only feasible when you have control over the HTML and know that the HTML will always have a particular structure or pattern, in which case we can do this:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1em;
}

div > p:first-child {
  font-size: 80%;
  color: #666;
}

p.st > span + span:nth-last-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

p.st > span:nth-last-child(2):not(strong + span) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Does not match any span elements: even though the last element is a span, that element doesn't have an immediate span sibling:</p>
  <p class="st">
    <span>Lorem</span>
    <span>ipsum</span>
    <em>
        <span>dolor</span>
        <span>sit</span>
      </em>
    <span>amet,</span> consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>The style rules specifically exclude the case of <code>strong + span</code>, so &quot;sit&quot; is not selected anymore, but this requires every special-case to be excluded, which is only possible if you can make guarantees about the HTML's structure.</p>
  <p class="st">
    <span>Lorem</span>
    <span>ipsum</span>
    <strong>dolor</strong>
    <span>sit</span>
    <strong>consectetur</strong> adipisicing elit.
  </p>

</div>

<div>
  <p>In this case, the style rule does correctly select the last span sibling pair:</p>
  <p class="st">
    <span>Lorem</span>
    <span>ipsum</span>
    <em>
        <span>dolor</span>
        <span>sit</span>
      </em>
    <span>amet,</span>
    <span>consectetur</span>
    <span>adipisicing</span>
    <span>elit.</span>
  </p>
</div>
```